# which app for virtual training shows real images of the current location taken from google street view?

Tags: training, indoor

I bought wahoo kickr. And would love to ride the uploaded GPX (so far, so good I found needed software) and would love to see update view from google street view when ridding.

Which app offer such feature?

So far my research shows that NONE of this:

CycleOps VirtualTraining

KinoMap

Zwift

Skuga

TrainerRoad

Comment: What about BKOOL?

Comment: There is Google earth not street view.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because question is about software, which is covered by http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/  Yes, its bike related, but the core question is "which app..." and that is not a bike question.  Sorry.

Comment: @andi Criggie and I rarely agree about closing questions, but in this case we do. It sounds like you've done the research, so if you want to help other cyclists, perhaps you could change your question to be like *how to set up realistic indoor training?* And then include what you've found out (required software and trainer combos, and what maps and images they use) in your own answer. Try to keep your question from asking for specific product recommendations, because that's OT here. Your answer can include them though.

Comment: I tried this a few years ago connecting my trainer to streetview - the problem was refresh rates, plus licencsing. I wrote a site for it - www.routeviewer.com - but no longer support it, or enable for trainers